# List Time Machine backups of a file

Tags: macos, time-machine

If I have a file or directory path, how can I list all Time Machine backups of that path?

Comment: You realize that Time Machine uses hard links - so each interval where that file was present will have a backup of that path? Look at the hard link counts and you can see how many instances of that version of the file are on the volume.

Comment: @bmike: That's true. I wasn't really concerned with duplicate entries though -- just interested in a list of dates that have backups, so I can easily  restore one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
# list Time Machine backups of a file starting with most recent

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: list_backups.sh filename"
    exit
fi

filename=`realpath "$1"`

# find root volume path
for vol in /Volumes/*; do 
    if [ "$(readlink "$vol")" = / ]; then 
        root_vol=$vol
    fi
done 

# prepend it to input path if necessary
if [[ "$filename" != /Volumes* ]]; then
    filename="$root_vol$filename"
fi

# remove /Volumes from input path
filename="${filename///Volumes}"

# loop over backups in reverse order
tmutil listbackups | tail -1000 -r |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [ -e "$line$filename" ]; then
        ls -ald "$line$filename"
    else
        echo "not in $line"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you didn't change the name of your main drive from 'Macintosh HD' to something else, you can run

```
ls -l /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/$(hostname -s)/*/Macintosh\ HD/$(realpath FILENAME)
```

to see all versions stored in TimeMachine.

PS `realpath` is only available if you have GNU coreutils installed (e.g. via brew). Otherwise use `$(pwd)/FILENAME` or (if this doesn't work because there are some symlinks involved) specify the full path instead.